# Saturation of Google Maps Highway Labels

Tags: google-maps

Not long ago, it was possible to **completely** desaturate a Google Map using the following code:

```
var styles = [
    {
        stylers: [
            { saturation: -100 }
        ]
    }
];
```

Since some weeks/months (I don't know exactly), however, this code desaturates the whole map **except for highway labels**, which remain blue:

[image]

How can I desaturate those highway labels again?

Comment: See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7980) in the google-maps-api issue tracker

Comment: Okay, thanks. I added an example in the issue tracker. Seems to be confirmed as a bug.